# SQL - How to returns values outside a date range query

Tags: sql

Hoping someone can help out here, I have the following data

```
Field 1 Field 2 Date     Data
1       1       12/09/14 1
2       2       12/09/14 1
3       1       11/09/14 1
4       3       11/09/14 1
```

I need to write an sql query that sums all "Data" based on a date range and then anything that matches in Field 2. So if a line is out of the date range but the value in Field 2 matches another line that is within the date range, it should be included

For example, if I was to query everything for the 12/09/14, I want to see the sum of line 1, 2 and 3.... as line 3 is outside of the date range but it matches line 1 in the "Field 2" column. Line 4 should not be included as it is outside the range and does not have a matching value in "Field 2"

Any ideas?

I've been playing around with variations of queries but it either selects only the date range values or everything :(

EDIT:

Ok I've given Rajesh answer a try and it doesn't seem to include the data outside the date range. I was expecting the final sum in this example to equal 3 but it's only showing 2

```
select sum(a) from (
select sum(batch_m2_nett) as a
from batch_inf
where batch_date = to_date('30/09/15','DD/MM/RR')
union
select sum(f2.batch_m2_nett) as a
from batch_inf f1
inner join batch_inf f2
on f1.batch_date = to_date('30/09/15','DD/MM/RR')
and f1.batch_opt_start_batch = f2.batch_opt_start_batch
and f2.batch_date != to_date('30/09/15','DD/MM/RR')
);

SUM(A)
------
2

SQL> select batch_no, batch_opt_start_batch, batch_date, batch_m2_nett from batch_inf where batch_no in (8811,8812,8814);
BATCH_NO BATCH_OPT_START_BATCH BATCH_DATE      BATCH_M2_NETT
-------- --------------------- --------------- -------------
  8811                    8814 30-SEP-15                   1
  8812                    8814 30-SEP-15                   1
  8814                    8814 01-OCT-15                   1
```

Comment: Please post your attempts

Comment: Sorry should have removed that line... my "attempts" where just basic "if date = blah". I'm guessing I need to pass values to a subquery but I'm unsure of how or the best way

Answer (score 0):

the first statement gets sum of data values where date matches

the second statement gets sum of data values where field2 of matched date row is matching with other rows using self join

```
select SUM(s)
from
(
select SUM(data) as s
from fields
where date ='12/09/14'
union
select sum(f2.data) as s
from fields f1
inner join fields f2
on f1.date ='12/09/14'
and f1.field2 = f2.field2
and f2.date != '12/09/14'
) T
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers... I couldn't get my reply to format correclty in a reply so I've added it to the original question